# Send id to controller from view in option tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to create my first web app. I have list of products and I want to sort products by name or price. The possible option I have in `<select>` tag and I try to use method `onchange` to send paramteres to my controller and there sort my list of products. When I debug my program I saw that as paramteres is send `null` value. Have you got some idea how can I resolve my problem?

```
<p>Sort by:</p>

<select onchange="location = this.value">
   <option value="@Url.Action("SortByString", new { id = "-----" })">-----</option>
   <option value="@Url.Action("SortByString", new { id = "Name" })">Name</option>
   <option value="@Url.Action("SortByString", new { id = "Price" })">Price</option>
</select>

public ActionResult SortByString(string sort){}
```

And as paramter sort is send null. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use one of the multiple overloads of `Url.Action()` method according to your need. In this case, you can use the fourth overload which is specified in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx).

So you need to change your code as following to pass exactly that parameter which you specified in your action method in the controller (If you don't want to define a custom route for your URL):

```
<p>Sort by:</p>

<select onchange="location = this.value">
   <option value="@Url.Action("SortByString", new { sort = "-----" })">-----</option>
   <option value="@Url.Action("SortByString", new { sort = "Name" })">Name</option>
   <option value="@Url.Action("SortByString", new { sort = "Price" })">Price</option>
</select>

public ActionResult SortByString(string sort){}
```